# Why does creating a file need at least five separate disk I/Os in Unix FFS?

Tags: filesystems, ext2

In *The Design and Implementation of a Log-Structured File System*, It says:

> It takes at least five separate
>   disk I/Os, each preceded by a seek, to create a new file in Unix FFS: two different accesses to the file’s attributes
>   plus one access each for the file’s data, the directory’s data,
>   and the directory’s attributes.

What's the "two different accesses to the file’s attributes" ? I can count once only which is the inode was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prof. Remzi Arpaci-Dusseau's book [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) has [an aside](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/file-ffs.pdf) about file creation:

> As an example, think about what data structures must be updated when a
>   file is created; assume, for this example, that the user creates a new
>   file `/foo/bar.txt` and that the file is one block long (4KB). The
>   file is new, and thus needs a new inode; thus, both the inode bitmap
>   and the newly allocated inode will be written to disk. The file also
>   has data in it and thus it too must be allocated; the data bitmap and
>   a data block will thus (eventually) be written to disk. Hence, at
>   least four writes to the current cylinder group will take place
>   (recall that these writes may be buffered in memory for a while before
>   they take place). But this is not all! In particular, when creating a
>   new file, you must also place the file in the file-system hierarchy,
>   i.e., the directory must be updated. Specifically, the parent
>   directory foo must be updated to add the entry for `bar.txt`; this
>   update may fit in an existing data block of `foo` or require a new
>   block to be allocated (with associated data bitmap). The inode of
>   `foo` must also be updated, both to reflect the new length of the
>   directory as well as to update time fields (such as
>   last-modified-time). Overall, it is a lot of work just to create a new
>   file! Perhaps next time you do so, you should be more thankful, or at
>   least surprised that it all works so well.

Comparing the two, I speculate that the authors included the data block update with file attribute access (even though they explicitly say that what they mean by file attributes are the "inode", it doesn't seem unreasonable to consider data location as a file attribute). At any rate, it looks like they've understated the disk accesses: it needs at least 6 from Prof. Arpaci-Dusseau's description:

1. inode bitmap
2. inode
3. data bitmap
4. file data
5. directory data
6. directory attributes